# WCF, The requestContext has been aborted

Tags: wcf, requestcontext

we had a wcf service and send lots of data for calculation.the code is standardized.
wsHttpBinding is used as communication protocal, and reliable session is enbaled.
The exception is occured occasionally. I catched the trace and got the exception wcf raised, wihch has no clue with root cause.

The exception

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException: requestContext has been aborted。

The stack trace  
在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.ThrowIfInvalidReply()
在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage9(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage8(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
在 System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
在 System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;CallbackGenerator&gt;b__2(AsyncCallback callback, IAsyncResult result)
在 System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
在 System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
在 System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.Dispatch()
在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableReplySessionChannel.ProcessSequencedMessage(RequestContext context, String action, WsrmSequencedMessageInfo info)
在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableReplySessionChannel.ProcessRequest(RequestContext context, WsrmMessageInfo info)
在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableReplySessionChannel.ProcessDemuxedRequest(RequestContext context, WsrmMessageInfo info)
在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableReplyListenerOverReply.ProcessSequencedItem(ReliableReplySessionChannel reliableChannel, RequestContext context, WsrmMessageInfo info)
在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableListenerOverDatagram`4.HandleReceiveComplete(TItem item, TInnerChannel channel)
在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableListenerOverDatagram`4.OnTryReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
在 System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
在 System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;CallbackGenerator&gt;b__2(AsyncCallback callback, IAsyncResult result)
在 System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
在 System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
在 System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
在 System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)
在 System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
在 System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
在 System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
在 System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
在 System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
在 System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
在 System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
```

Comment: Does this lead to a failure of any kind? Is there any other information in the event log?

Comment: This made the channel to the faulted state, then the client cannot send the message.